# Creating a dictionary-type structure in Access/Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I want to declare something like so:

```
dictionaryItem = {("Key1", "Value1"}, {"Key2", "Value2"} ... }
```

But cannot get the syntax right. If not I'd like to make two arrays with initial values (but could not get this working either no matter how I tried to write it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to me you're describing a Scripting Dictionary.  See if this is satisfactory.

```
Dim dct As Object
Set dct = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dct.Add "Key1", "Value1"
dct.Add "Key2", "Value2"
Debug.Print dct.Count
Debug.Print dct("Key1")
Debug.Print dct("Key2")
Set dct = Nothing
```

Comment: Can you use a list of values instead of a single value?

Comment: A dictionary will accept an array for the item value, but not for the key.